# ERROR running force:apex:test:run: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Tags: apex, trigger

```
    @istest
    public class BatchStatusNewCCDTest {
        public static Integer numOfCases = 5;
        @isTest static void schedulerTest()
        {
    
            // Create Test
            CaseFactory cf   = new CaseFactory();
    
            Map<String, Object> CaseFields = new Map<String, Object>
            {
                'Status__c' => 'Closed',
                'Group__c' => 'Pathology/Tertiary',
                'Priority' =>'Routine',
                'RecordTypeId' => '0124T000000mMskQAE',
                'New_Date__c' => Date.today(),
                'On_Hold_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
                'Pending_Provider_Notes_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
                'Pending_Provider_Diagnosis_Code_Date__c

' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Pending_Provider_Order_Modification_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Pending_Patient_Insurance_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Pending_Submission_Date__c' => Date.today() -  Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Order_Submitted_Date__c' => Date.today() -  Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Order_Resubmitted_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Order_Denied_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Order_Modification_Submitted_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Payer_Request_for_Info_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Auth_Submitted_to_Alt_Payer_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Order_Approved_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Pending_Biopsy_Prep_Work_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Pending_Schedule_by_Patient_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Pending_Schedule_by_TOI_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Pending_Processing_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Patient_Noncompliant_Date__c' => Date.today() - Integer.valueof((Math.random() * 45)),
            'Closed_Date__c' => Date.today() - 1
        };

        List<Case> Cases = cf.make(CaseFields, numOfCases, true);

    }
}
```

For Some Reason when I run tests I get the following Output:

```
 --loglevel error

ERROR:  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["projectdir"]

Unhandled rejection TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["projectdir"]

ERROR running force:apex:test:run:  Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

I have never seen this before, so I am bit lost for words on this. I am assuming my code is working, its something with the extension?

Here is the full path:

/Users/matthewmetros/Dropbox/My Mac (Matthew’s MacBook Pro)/Documents/GitHub/TOI/.sfdx/tools/testresults/apex --loglevel error

Comment: I would suggest you try executing the test run from a path that does not contain spaces, apostrophes, or parentheses. If you want to be thorough eliminate the culprits one at a time! Then consider filing an issue on GitHub.